# Not able to add meta boxes to multiple post types

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

For some reason, I'm not able to add meta boxes to multiple post types.
According to [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), I should be able to use an array of post types.

This works:

```
add_meta_box( 
  'Bilder', 
  __('Bilder'), 
  'project_custom_meta_box_images',
  'page', // <---- works
  'normal', 
  'default' 
);
```

And this does not work:

```
add_meta_box( 
  'Bilder', 
  __('Bilder'), 
  'project_custom_meta_box_images',
  array('page', 'post'),  // <---- does not work
  'normal', 
  'default' 
);
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Actually the documentation says the parameter only accepts a `string` argument and the example shows how to add the meta box to multiple post types by looping an array

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to @koala_dev's comment, try using a `foreach` loop:

```
$types = array( 'post', 'page' );
foreach ( $types as $type ) {
    add_meta_box( 
        'Bilder', 
        __('Bilder'), 
        'project_custom_meta_box_images',
        $type,
        'normal', 
        'default' 
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's what I did.